# Hotkey for commenting ruby code in Aptana Studio 3 not Working with german keyboard

Tags: ruby, keyboard, comments, hotkeys, aptana

In **Aptana Studio 3** (latest version and all previous versions of 3) I am not able to comment lines via keyboard shortcuts. I have a **german keyboard layout**.

The default shortcut is CTRL + /, but this doesn't work. Even setting the shortcut in *Preferences/General/Keys* doesn't work. The command is called *Python Toggle Comment*.

Using the *Commands* menu and use *Source -> Comments -> Comment Line / Selection* comments the lines correctly. In this menu I can also see the hotkey CTRL + / behind the menu entry.

It would increase the speed of writing and testing code, if I could use the hotkey. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try pulling down a copy of the Source ruble and edit the keybinding to one that works for you. Commands > Source > Edit this bundle. It'll try to do a git clone of the bundle into your "Documents/Aptana Rubles/source.ruble" folder. Then you can edit commands/toggle_comment.rb and change the binding to what works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately the git clone doesn't work ('Grabbing bundle Source...' has encountered a problem. Git clone failed: Cloning into /home/user/Aptana Rubles/source.ruble...). Giving all permissions (777) to the folder does not help. Internet connection is working for Aptana Studio (autoupdate works).
So this is why I can not try your answer.

Comment: Well, you can try manually cloning the ruble, by using command line git to grab it: `cd /home/user/Aptana Rubles;git clone git://github.com/aptana/source.ruble.git`

Comment: Ah, now it worked. Problem was the proxy (he doesnt't know git, so I had to manually grab the https-ressource with ´git clone https://github.com/aptana/source.ruble.git´ Then I changed `cmd.key_binding = ["M1+/", "M1+7", "M1+M2+C"]` to `cmd.key_binding = ["M1+/", "M1+7", "M1+M2+C", "M1+#"]`

Comment: If you failed to connect to "git://github.com/...". Try git with http "git clone https://github.com/aptana/source.ruble.git". If you don't have git, download the zip on https://github.com/aptana/source.ruble